# What to do instead of adding/changing global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming and I keep reading everywhere "using methods to change global variables is not good coding. Use very little global variables and definitely don't change them". I can't seem to find a good explanation of why or what *should* be done.

Lets say I want to have some sort of a game. And it has variable `health=100`. Now I figured this should be a global variable and not inside a class/object, but that would also mean I would need to adjust it and so on by doing something like:

```
def minushealth():
    global health
    health -= 20
```

I can't really seem to figure this out and maybe there is just something simple I don't know here.

Comment: Why should it not be in a class/object?  I assume you're making a simple game, how about making a class for the `Player` and make `health` a variable inside that class?

Comment: In terms of *why* to avoid global variables, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `health` an explicit argument to and return value from the function:

```
def minus_health(health):
   return health - 20
```

then assign the return value when you call it:

```
health = minus_health(health)
```

Even better, get rid of the "magic number" with an optional second argument:

```
def minus_health(health, amount=20):
   return health - amount
```

Note that you can now test `minus_health` like:

```
assert minus_health(100) == 80
```

whereas if you implemented with `global`, you would have to do:

```
health = 100
minus_health()
assert health == 80
```

It might not seem like a huge problem in this simple example, but as your program gets more complex you have much more setup and tear-down to do, whereas a well-isolated function will still be effectively testable in one line.

Answer (score 1):

jonrsharpe's answer is on point.

But for a game type answer you'd be better off using the class/attribute solution which would look like:

```
player_object.minus_health()
```

Where minus_health would look like:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        __health = 100

    def minus_health(self):
        self.__health -= 20
```

Of course this doesn't take into account if the health goes below 0, etc. But you should get the idea. This way allows all "Players" to have separate health attributes.

Comment: I would use at most a single underscore, and generally only if I wanted to use a property - name mangling is a pain, and "we're all consenting adults"!

Comment: Agreed, I'm just used to using a double underscore for 'truly private' variables out of habit for work. I can't remember the exact reason we do it that way. It's something along the lines of if you use a double underscore the interpreter actually remaps your variable name to something like _module_variable, where as with a single underscore it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `Player` class shown in another answer is probably going to be where you end up, but just an explanation of arguments to a function, you can only modify arguments that are *mutable*.  In your specify case, an approach similar to the `Player` class, but simpler, is to manage your state in a `dict` and then pass that dict into the function to modify an attribute:

```
def minus_health(entity, amount=-20):
    entity['health']+=amount

# Use like so
player = dict(name='John', health=100)
minus_health(player)
```

`list`s and `object`s are also mutable and will work in a similar way, i.e. their contents can be modified inside the function.